# Is the regular representation just another way of saying the standard representation?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

the question may be a little silly but I want to clarify things.

***EDIT:*** Assuming the standard representation is the regular representation then what is the difference between the standard(regular) representation and the permutation representation?

Comment: context? link to what you are reading?

Comment: Linear representations of finite groups by J.P. Serre

Comment: What do you mean by the "standard representation"?  And what do you mean by "the permutation representation"?  ("Permutation representation" has a standard meaning, but "**the** permutation representation" does not.)

Comment: @Eric Wofsey yes I am talking about permutation representation where the group G acts on a finite set X

Comment: @EricWofsey this is where I read upon about the standard representation: http://www.mit.edu/~ivogt/Representation_Theory.pdf

Comment: If $G$ is a permutation group then the set $X$ it acts on is the standard representation, which is distinct from the regular representation (which is usually $G$'s action on itself by left multiplication, although some sources will use left regular and right regular to distinguish). Similarly if $G$ is a matrix subgroup of $GL(V)$ then $V$ is the standard representation.

Comment: @arctictern, tx this makes a lot of sense to me. Your comment is quite old, but I was wondering, when $X$ is chosen to be the set of element of $G$, if the regular and the standard representations are not currently matching.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing while reading Serre's book.  I can't put this response as a comment (don't have a reputation of 50 or higher).

The regular (standard) representation is a special and  important type of a permutation representation.

Wikipedia, ([Regular Representation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_representation), gives the following distinction (in bold)

"To say that G acts on itself by multiplication is tautological. If we consider this action as a permutation representation it is characterised as having a single orbit and stabilizer the identity subgroup {e} of G. The regular representation of G, for a given field K, is the linear representation made by taking this permutation representation as a set of basis vectors of a vector space over K. **The significance is that while the permutation representation doesn't decompose - it is transitive - the regular representation in general breaks up into smaller representations.** For example, if G is a finite group and K is the complex number field, the regular representation decomposes as a direct sum of irreducible representations, with each irreducible representation appearing in the decomposition with multiplicity its dimension. The number of these irreducibles is equal to the number of conjugacy classes of G."

This post answers your question with a good example: [The difference between permutation representation and standard representation of symmetric group  S3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187490/the-difference-between-permutation-representation-and-standard-representation-of?rq=1)

Comment: this is confusing because the notion of permutation rep in your wikipedia quote (permutation rep = $G$-set) is different to the notion of rep in the link at the bottom of your answer, where it means a linear representation obtained from a $G$-set.