# Understanding $\mathfrak{S}_n$ invariant algebras via the Orlik-Solomon algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters, matroids

I am trying to understand invariant algebras for nontrivial characters. The gist of my question is confusion over the definition and an equivalent condition given in Stanley's survey paper *Invariants Of Finite Groups And Their Applications To Combinatorics*. I worked through an example, and my conclusion seems wrong, but I don't understand why and I was hoping someone could see where I went wrong.

### My work

I worked through an example of the Orlik-Solomon algebra $A$ of the rank-2 braid arrangement $$\{x_i = x_j: 1 \leq i < j\leq 3\},$$ which is a skew-commutative algebra (I take coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$) with basis
$$\{1, e_{(1,2)}, e_{(1,3)}, e_{(2,3)}, e_{(1,2)}e_{(1,3)}, e_{(1,2)}e_{(2,3)} \}$$
and the additional relation $e_{(1,3)}e_{(2,3)} = e_{(1,2)}e_{(1,3)} - e_{(1,2)}e_{(2,3)}$. It is also graded by the number of generators $e_{(i,j)}$.

I want to think of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_3$ acting on the coordinates of the braid arangment, so for example the involution $(1,2) \in \mathfrak{S}_3$ acts like $(1,2) \cdot e_{(1,3)} = e_{(2,3)}$. I am also treating the subscripts as a set so that $e_{(1,2)} = e_{(2,1)}$.

After going through the character computation by explicitly writing the group action as a matrix, I came to the following conclusion: $A \cong S^{(3)} \oplus S^{(3)} \oplus S^{(2,1)} \oplus S^{(2,1)}$, where $S^{\lambda}$ is the Specht module indexed by $\lambda \vdash 3$.
My thinking was that $\sigma \cdot 1 = 1$, so $A_0$ (the degree-0 homogeneous piece of $A$) is isomorphic to the trivial representation.
Then $A_1$ is the permutation representation, which decomposes into $S^{(3)} \oplus S^{(2,1)}$. Finally, $A_2$ is the regular representation $S^{(2,1)}$. (I feel ok about this, but would love to hear if this is right or wrong.)

**Edit:** it is not the regular representation, it is the standard representation, as pointed out in the comments.

Now, I want to understand the two invariant algebras $A^{\mathfrak{S}_3}_{(3)}$ and $A^{\mathfrak{S}_3}_{(2,1)}$.
We can change basis for $A_1$ to write it as the span of $\{e_{(1,2)}+e_{(1,3)} + e_{(2,3)}, e_{(1,2)}- e_{(1,3)}, e_{(1,3)} - e_{(2,3)}\}$ which decomposes it into the trivial representation (on $e_{(1,2)}+e_{(1,3)} + e_{(2,3)}$) and the regular representation (on $e_{(1,2)}- e_{(1,3)}, e_{(1,3)} - e_{(2,3)}$). The basis for the $(2,1)$ isotypic component on $A_2$ is the same as the basis for $A_2$.

So then bases for the two isotypic components $A_{(3)}$ and $A_{(2,1)}$ are:
$$A_{(1,1,1)} : \{ 1,\, e_{(1,2)}+e_{(1,3)} + e_{(2,3)}\}$$
and
$$A_{(2,1)} : \{e_{(1,2)}- e_{(1,3)},\, e_{(1,3)} - e_{(2,3)},e_{(1,2)}e_{(1,3)}, e_{(1,2)}e_{(2,3)} \}.$$

Stanley defines the invariants to be $R_\chi^G$ (he does define them on a polynomial ring, but it is unclear to me if this distinction matters for this example) where $R_\chi^G$ is the isotypic component associated to the character $\chi$. So, $A_{(3)}^{\mathfrak{S}_3}$ should be the span of $\{ 1,\, e_{(1,2)}+e_{(1,3)} + e_{(2,3)}\}$ and $A_{(2,1)}^{\mathfrak{S}_3}$ should be the span of $\{e_{(1,2)}- e_{(1,3)},\, e_{(1,3)} - e_{(2,3)}\}$. Up to this point, I thought everything had made sense to me.

### My confusion

Stanley says,

> In the special case $\chi$ is linear (i.e.,$\chi$ is a homomorphism $G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$), then the condition $f \in R^G_\chi$ is equivalent to $M(f) = \chi(M)f$ for all $M \in G$.

From my understanding this means that the invariant $A_\chi^{\mathfrak{S}_3}$ should be the following intersection of kernels:
$$ \bigcap_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_3} \ker ( x \mapsto \sigma \cdot d - \chi(\sigma) x). $$
However, I went to explicitly compute that intersection, and got some confusing results.

Taking $\chi$ to be the trivial character, things made sense.
However, taking $\chi$ to be the character of the regular representation, and computing for conjugacy class representatives $()$, $(12)$ and $(123)$ (in cycle notation), I found that

| $\sigma$ | $\chi(\sigma)$ | $f$ | $\sigma \cdot f - \chi(\sigma)f $ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $() $ | $2$ | $e_{(1,2)}-e_{(1,3)}$ | $-e_{(1,2)}+e_{(1,3)}\neq 0$ |
| " | " | $e_{(1,3)}-e_{(2,3)}$ | $-e_{(1,2)}+e_{(1,3)}\neq 0$ |
| " | " | $e_{(1,2)}e_{(1,3)}$ | $-e_{(1,2)}e_{(1,3)} \neq 0$ |
| " | " | $e_{(1,2)}e_{(2,3)}$ | $-e_{(1,2)}e_{(2,3)} \neq 0$ |
| $(12)$ | $0$ | $e_{(1,2)}-e_{(1,3)}$ | $e_{(1,2)}-e_{(2,3)}\neq 0$ |
| " | " | $e_{(1,3)}-e_{(2,3)}$ | $e_{(2,3)}-e_{(1,3)}\neq 0$ |
| " | " | $e_{(1,2)}e_{(1,3)}$ | $e_{(1,2)}e_{(2,3)} \neq 0$ |
| " | " | $e_{(1,2)}e_{(2,3)}$ | $e_{(1,2)}e_{(1,3)} \neq 0$ |
| $(123)$ | $-1$ | $e_{(1,2)}-e_{(1,3)}$ | $e_{(2,3)}-e_{(1,2)} + e_{(1,2)} -e_{(1,3)} = e_{(2,3)} - e_{(1,3)} \neq 0$ |
| " | " | $e_{(1,3)}-e_{(2,3)}$ | $e_{(1,2)}-e_{()} + e_{(1,2)} -e_{(1,3)} = e_{(2,3)} - e_{(1,3)} \neq 0$ |
| " | " | $e_{(1,2)}e_{(1,3)}$ | $e_{(2,3)}e_{(1,2)} + 2e_{(1,2)}e_{(1,3)} \neq 0 $ |
| " | " | $e_{(1,2)}e_{(2,3)}$ | $e_{(2,3)}e_{(1,3)} + 2e_{(1,2)}e_{(2,3)} = e_{(1,2)}e_{(2,3)} + e_{(1,2)}e_{(1,3)} \neq 0$ |

This leads me to believe that $ \bigcap_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_3} \ker ( x \mapsto \sigma \cdot d - \chi(\sigma) x)$ is not the same as the previously computed isotypic component.

I wish to compute the invariant algebra as a kernel. Is there a way to do this for noncommutative (or just skew-commutative) underlying algebra? Or am I somehow misunderstanding the relationship between the isotypic component and the kernel I described? Or maybe I am wrongly assuming that the character I used is linear?

Any help you could provide would be much appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: When you say "regular representation", you mean "standard representation". The former has dimension $n-1$, the latter $n!$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am confused, because this post seemed to indicate that they were the same: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065206/is-the-regular-representation-just-another-way-of-syaing-the-standard-representa

Comment: The post you linked does not indicate they are the same. The regular representation of a group $G$ over a field $k$ is always the group algebra $kG$. The standard representation is more context-dependent, but typically means something like "the most reasonable defining representation". For instance, the standard representation of a dihedral group is its action on the appropriate polygon.

Comment: Ah I see. So is the entirety of $A_1$ then the regular representation?

Comment: No, the regular representation here would be 6-dimensional. I'd probably call $A_1$ the permutation representation, since in that basis the elements act as permutation matrices. The standard representation is one summand of the permutation representation. The regular representation would be the "larger" action of $S_3$ on itself (or more precisely, acting linearly on a vector space with basis indexed by itself).

Comment: Ah! Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stanley's remark only applies to linear characters, i.e. $\chi(1) = 1$, i.e. 1-dimensional representations. The standard representation is not 1-dimensional.

Comment: The word "linear" might be the source of confusion here. By a historical accident, in the context of a character (itself a word of many meanings), it doesn't mean "linear map"; it means "group homomorphism" (i.e., the character of a 1-dimensional representation).

Comment: @darij grinberg Yes, good point Darij. (Hope you've been well through the pandemic.) I've actually started to follow another tradition and refer to them as "semi-invariants". My entry to that phrasing was through some work of Vic Reiner. It's evocative and only slightly longer.

Comment: @darijgrinberg yes, I think that was the source of my confusion. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson, which work of Reiner introduced you to that phrasing?

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson: I'm doing fine; how are you? My preferred name for these not-quite-invariants is "twisted invariants", but I don't know how alone I am with that convention and how alone the latter is with its use of the word "twisted".

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm doing well, moving to USC essentially right now, looking forward to working with Greta, Jason, and Sami for a bit! I've actually considered the phrasing "twisted invariants" in the spirit of "twisted actions", and I think it's eminently reasonable, I've just never seen it in print.

Comment: @tekay-squared It turns out my memory was faulty. It was actually a paper of Anne Shepler, "Semi-invariants of Finite Reflection Groups", *Journal of Algebra* (1999). [I was mixing it up with a recent paper by Reiner--Shepler--Sommers, "Invariant theory for coincidental complex reflection groups", *Mathematische Zeitschrift* (2021).]

Comment: Thanks for the reference!